# firestore rules matching parent data, only work in simulator

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm trying to make a simple direct message part. I have a document with some meta informations and a subcollection with the single messages. 
When I try to get the messages the rules are valid in the simulator, but in js I get everytime: *Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions*.

**The mongodb structure:**

- chatRooms

  - roomId

    - metaInformation (senderId/Name, recieverId/Name, timestamp, etc.)
    - messages

      - messageId

        - name
        - text
        - timestamp

**The rules:**

```
match /chatRooms/{chatRoom}  {
  allow create: if request.auth.uid != null;
  allow update, delete: if resource.data.uid == request.auth.uid;   

  function isChatPartner() {
   return parentDoc().receiverId == request.auth.uid || parentDoc().senderId == request.auth.uid;
  }

  function parentDoc() {
    return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/chatRooms/$(chatroom)).data;
  }

  match /messages/{message} {
    allow read: if isChatPartner();
  }

}
```

**The js-request:**

```
db.collection("chatRoom").doc(_roomId).collection("messages").get().then(msg => {
   console.log(msg);
})
```

Has anyone an idea what maybe could be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your database and rules don't match.  In the rule, the top level collection is called "chatRooms", but in your code, it's called "chatRoom".  The collection names need to match exactly.

There's another problem.  Your code is trying to get all of the documents in the subcollection, but the rules don't allow that.  The rules are checking certain fields for access.  This won't work in security rules, since [rules are not filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#rules_are_not_filters) (be sure to read and understand those docs).  The query must only request documents that will definitely pass the rules - the rules will not check each document and exclude the ones that don't match.